# I am getting syntax error in my code for my first website

Tags: php

I am getting a error on line 1 and line 6 i spaced them out to allow for you to see.

Could tell what is wrong with the following code?

```
/* Data Variables */
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email= $_POST['Email'];
$comments = $_POST['Message'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$signup= $_POST['signup']


$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Comments: $comments <br>
Where did you find us : $where <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($to, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);
```

Comment: And the errors that you're getting are? Those little error messages are there for a reason

Comment: 1. What error are you getting, exactly? 2. Are you sure the `$_POST` variables are set, if not: PHP will emit a warning, wrap every `$name = $_POST['Name'];` statement in an `if (isset($_POST['Name']))` block. 3. Please add comments next to the lines that cause errors

Comment: Where are `$where`, `$emailSubject`, and `$to` defined. Also you have a semicolon missing on the `$signup` line

Comment: Have you remembered your `<?php` opening tag?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semicolon on line 6

```
$signup= $_POST['signup'];
```